# Error while trying to INSERT into a reference table

Tags: postgresql

These are the tables created and the some of the inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE aluno(
        aluno_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        aluno_nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        aluno_cpf CHAR(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        genero CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
        idade SMALLINT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Rafael Almeida Azevedo',65155524407,'M','18');
INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Vinícius Correia Barbosa',49266274348,'M','19');
INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Kauan Goncalves Costa',97853049498,'M','22');
INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Samuel Correia Sousa',77050313459,'M','21');
INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Diogo Pereira Barros',12981340212,'M','24');
INSERT INTO aluno(aluno_nome, aluno_cpf, genero, idade) VALUES ('Marcos Cardoso Cavalcanti',59681262050,'M','18');


CREATE TABLE curso(
        curso_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        curso_codigo SMALLINT UNIQUE,
        curso_nome VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO curso(curso_codigo, curso_nome) VALUES('101','Ciência da Computação');
INSERT INTO curso(curso_codigo, curso_nome) VALUES('102','Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas');
INSERT INTO curso(curso_codigo, curso_nome) VALUES('103','Engenharia de Software');
INSERT INTO curso(curso_codigo, curso_nome) VALUES('104','Tecnologia da Informação');


// these are the inserts I cant get to work

CREATE TABLE aluno_curso(
        aluno_curso_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        aluno_id INTEGER UNIQUE REFERENCES aluno(aluno_id),
        curso_id INTEGER UNIQUE REFERENCES curso(curso_id)
)

INSERT INTO aluno_curso(aluno_id, curso_id) VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO aluno_curso(aluno_id, curso_id) VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO aluno_curso(aluno_id, curso_id) VALUES (3,1);
```

I've been getting [Code: 0, SQL State: 23505] error but I cant fix it, I tried recreating the tables and changing up the inserts. Also tried to use `SELECT MAX(curso_id) FROM curso;` and `SELECT nextval('curso_id') from curso;` but I cant get nextval to work, it says the relation does not exist

Comment: Not sure why you expect `INSERT INTO aluno_curso(aluno_id, curso_id) VALUES (1,4);` to work a there is no `aluno_curso` table in your example.

Comment: I edited the post but the table does exist

Comment: `curso_id` is a column, not a sequence, so `nextval` will not work on it. The default name of the sequence you created `<table>_<column>_seq`, hence should be `curso_curso_id_seq` in your case. If you want to select only 1 next value, just do `SELECT nextval(curso_curso_id_seq)`, no `FROM` clause needed.

Comment: Nextval is 5 as expected, what should I do next?

Comment: If it does not work now, drop the tables and try again. Your queries work for me. As an option, you could review why you thought you needed column `aluno_curso_id`; if the objective is to uniquely identify a record, then the other 2 columns will do a fine job for it already since they are unique and this one looks redundant. Finally, I suggest you add `RETURNING aluno_id` or `RETURNING curso_id` on your inserts to get the values of  the inserted records.

Comment: I dropped all tables and it worked, thank you Atmo

Comment: What is the complete error message when you do `INSERT INTO aluno_curso(aluno_id, curso_id) VALUES (1,4);` ?

Answer (score 0):

What did you tried?
If you mean to insert them to `aluno_curso` table, it is not exist.
If you try to create a foreign key, this is not the way.

You can try to create this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `aluno_curso` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aluno_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `curso_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: I edited the post with the CREATE TABLE of aluno_curso, forgot to include it before

Comment: *`* is a MySQL thing and will fail in Postgres, so this is not a correct answer.